# Difference between "value" and "valorize"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Beyond the definitions of both words, I can't find which is best in which context.

If I mean giving impontance to something, which one should I use?

If I mean giving more value ($) to something, which one should I use?

If I want to mean both?

By example: Valorize your data / Value your data ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Is 'valorize' in the dictionary? If it is, it is very rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words have different meanings.

'valorize' is a really rare word, and specifically means to artificially maintain the price of something by government intervention. So don't use it unless you are intending to have the government impose price controls on your data.

'value' can mean 'giving importance', so is probably the one you want in that case. But beware - 'value your data' can mean a lot of things, and not everybody would interpret it to mean 'make more important'.

If you want to increase the amount your data sells for then "increase the value of' is probably what you mean.

Comment: Actually, you'd *increase the price of* your data.  The actual *value* might well remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

As @DJClayworth says, you should probably forget you ever came across *valorize* - it doesn't figure in most people's vocabularies, and if you come across it at all it'd probably be an (erroneous, imho) attempt to convey the sense of either *to validate* or *to evaluate*.

I think you'd normally speak of ***adding value to*** your data, but you might also ***monetise*** it.

Comment: "Value your data" would normally be used in the sense of *"if you value your data"*, like *"if you think your data is important"*.

Answer (score 2):

I usually see "valorize" in student dissertations or in business reports. In my opinion, the writers appear to feel this gives what they're writing more importance or validation. To me, it's just an irritant as well as a word that puts a wall between writer and reader. I used to be a freelance copyeditor and would often leave a note on the margin suggesting the use of a different word. Sometimes I succeeded and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the persons who have spoken here are all US nationals? This term was coined by Karl Marx originally as Verwertung, it is one of the "untranslatables". It is widely used in French and it gained a new meaning in French, close to the English valuation. It looks like in the US, it kept its original meaning, the one that was conveyed in the German term. Given that Karl Marx is automatically associated with communism, hence avoided in the US..

Answer (score 0):

I think the government and academic cases are valid. AND I see valorization most often in the context of non-English (Latinate) speakers. Valorization is a closer cognate to the word in the original language and follows translation rules better than valuation. It's not wrong, just cognitively easier on the speaker.